# Ethernet interface disappeared from macOS. How to restore?

Tags: macos, imac, macos-ventura

I'm using an iMac with macOS 13 (Ventura).

Since yesterday the Ethernet interface simply disappeared from my iMac and I’m unable to connect via cable anymore, only Wi-Fi.

Tried to add it again on Settings, but no luck.

Ethernet shows up as “Apple T2 Controller” in “System Settings > General > About > System Report… > Hardware > Ethernet” and in “System Report > Network” something shows as “Thunderbolt bridge,” type Ethernet. I have already rebooted several times and nothing has changed.

What could have happened?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Reboot, just in case the Ethernet driver kext got magically unloaded or something. And then check whether or not the Ethernet shows up in `System Settings > General > About > System Report… > Hardware > Ethernet`, as well was `System Report… > Network`.

Comment: Ethernet shows up as 'Apple T2 Controller' on System Settings > General > About > System Report… > Hardware > Ethernet, and on System Report > Network something shows as 'Thunderbolt bridge', type Ethernet. Already rebooted several times.

Comment: Run Apple's hardware diagnostics: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731

Comment: @Spiff Tried but looks like this procedure (hold D) won't work on an Imac as the keyboard probably is not connected on the first moments of rebooting

Comment: If you have a Bluetooth keyboard, you have to hit any boot-time keys *as you hear the boot chime trailing off*. If you hit them any sooner, the system assumes you have broken (stuck down) keys on your keyboard and ignores them. If you hit them any later, you might miss the window of time considered "at the start of boot". So press down D as you hear the boot chime trailing off, and hold it until you can tell that it's entering diags mode. If you have a USB keyboard handy that you can use for this temporarily, that's better than trying to time things just right with a Bluetooth keyboard.

Comment: @Spiff Thanks, i could run diagnostics, but it returned 'No issues found'. Looks like my last resource would be a fresh re-install of Ventura, but this would be a hassle as i'd need to setup my environment again :-x

Comment: If I were you, I'd just add an APFS volume to my existing APFS container, and install a clean install of Ventura there (or do the same with an external drive like a USB flash drive). That way you can see if a clean install fixes it, without messing up your current environment. I still have some suspicion that your Ethernet chipset has physically gone AWOL. I think that T2 controller is just how your iMac's main chipset talks to the T2 chip; I seem to recall Apple used a network-like interface between those chips. So a clean OS install may just prove your Ethernet hardware is gone.

Comment: That's odd, i've been using Apple computers for decades and never had something like this. One thing i remembered : coincidence or not, the issue started after i uninstalled an app called 'Ethernet status'